# Unable to display out the remaining date

Tags: java, android, date

My program will get data from database and show it in a `Listview`. Now I get the date from database and compare it with my current date and count the remaining day. I successfully got the data and show it in a listview, but my remaining day code is not working. Any help will be appreciated!

```java
    List<HashMap<String,Object>> aList = newArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
    for (int i = 0; i<records.size(); i++) {
        HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put("txt", records.get(i).getAssname());
        hm.put("txt2", records.get(i).getAssTime());

        String ez = records.get(i).getAssTime();
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

        //count the remain day
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat dd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy");
            Date date1= dd.parse(ez);
            Date date2 = today.getTime();
            long diff = Math.abs(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime());
            long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

            hm.put("txt3", String.valueOf(diffDays));

        } catch (Exception e1) {
        }
        aList.add(hm);
    }

    // Keys used in Hashmap
    String[] from = {"txt","txt2","txt3"};

    // Ids of views in listview_layout
    int[] to = { R.id.assigment_name,R.id.assigment_ATime, R.id.assigment_remain};

    // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
    // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.view_assignment_entry, from, to);
```

What's wrong with my code ?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? are you getting wrong output or any exception. Please Explain.

Comment: no error when running and the listview should show out my remain day but the listview  remain textview result is empty

Comment: Could you provide some log printing date1, date2 and diff days? I wonder if it could be a casting error due the division. But aside from this, it seems your code should be working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try change

```
long diff = Math.abs(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime());
long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

to

```
long diff = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
long diffDays  = Math.abs(TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final long DAY_MILLIS =  24* 60 * 60*1000 ;  

int Days = (int) ((date_1.getTime() - date_2.getTime())/ DAY_MILLIS );
```

or  you can use Joda time library for Java.

```
Days d = Days.daysBetween(startDate, endDate);  
int days = d.getDays();
```

I hope it will help you...!